# How to enable SSL in Oracle 11g listener

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Currently, using oracle 11g(express edition) with plain socket 1521 and wanted to set up with SSL. I trying to enable\add SSL to exist oracle 11g.
And trying to understand, what is wallet manager and how to config SSL in existing port using [SSL config](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asossl.htm#i1009600).
I am unable to locate the wallet manager in the express edition.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. Wallet doesn't work in Oracle XE.

---

I don't know "*how to enable SSL in existing port 1521*" (question you posted in a comment), I've never done that.

However, in [this discussion](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/2614488/how-to-configure-oracle-xe-with-apache-and-ssl), ApexPhil said:

> I know Wallet isn't part of XE but you can still use Wallets in XE. Just use another version of the database to make your Wallet file and then use that file in XE. I've done this before and it works.

> If you don't have access to a database with Wallet Manager installed, here is someone who has created a wallet file without Wallet Manager: https://blog.hazrulnizam.com/openssl-workaround-oracle-xe-wallet/

> I don't know whether that method works but creating one with Wallet Manager definitely will.

See if it helps.

Comment: Then how to enable SSL in existing port 1521 is default.

Comment: I added some more info into the answer; have a look, please.